# Terraform Nested Loop

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

As an absolute beginner in Terraform, I'm looking to assign AWS permissions to IAM users. I have a set of usernames and managed policies that I'd like to use for this task. Here are my variables:

```
variable "username" {
        type = list(string)
    default = ["name1" ,"name2" , "name3"]
  
}

variable "managedpolicy" {
    type = list(string)
    default = [
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess",
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess"
    ]
}
```

All users will have these 3 permissions. How to achieve this task. Do I need to use nested loop.

For now I can do for one user as below file.

```
provider "aws" {
         region = "ap-southeast-1"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "attach" {
  user       = var.user
  policy_arn = each.value
  for_each   = toset(var.managedpolicy)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create a local variable, which contains all combinations of `username` and `managedpolicy` using the [setproduct](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct) function. Then you can use this local variable in the for each statement when attaching the policies.

```
locals {
combinations = {for val in setproduct(var.username, var.managedpolicy):
                "${val[0]}-${val[1]}" => val}  
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "attach" {
  for_each   = local.combinations
  user       = each.value[0]
  policy_arn = each.value[1]
}
```